# How can I sync application between multiple computers?

Tags: 12.04, sync

I have three laptops, all running 12.04 (they were running 11.10). I have backups working to Ubuntu One for my primary laptop, and folder synchronization of my Documents, Pictures and Music folders working to all three laptops. I like the idea of being able to work on a document on my primary laptop, head out with a netbook and do some quick work on the same document, then finish it up on the third and not worry whether I grab a netbook, a low-end laptop or the bigger, heavier one.

I'd like to keep applications synchronized across all three laptops. I saw where you can do that using the Ubuntu Software Center, then click Installed, File and Synch between Computers. When I do that - I don't see my three laptops listed. When I log in to Ubuntu One - I see all three laptops. I can synch my folders just fine. Not sure how to synch my apps.

Comment: You should sign in eith the ubuntu account from all 3 computers and then follow the steps below-

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy.

1. Go to the Software Center and and see the option of SYNC BETWEEN COMPUTERS option under the file menu.
2. As you click on it you will see your computer registered and a list of all apps on your computer
3. When you will install fresh,that computer will be considered a new computer.
4. You just have to sign in in your ubuntu account and your previous computer will be shown.
5. Click on it,you'll get a list of all apps.Select install on the app you want to install.

PS:For this you need a "SINGLE SIGN ON UBUNTU ACCOUNT"(b4 reinstalling create it so that your pc is syncd)

Comment: I've done your above 5 steps, but when I click on the other computer (step 5), it presents me with an empty list, regardless of whether or not the two computers have the same installations or not.  Any idea what might be (not) happening?

Comment: On Ubuntu Forums someone else is having essentially the same problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969664

Comment: you signed in on all 3 computers?? if yes then check on all 3 computers,what is the last sync time...under the list you will see it...is it sometime recently??

Comment: Yes, the sync time is listed as just a couple minutes ago on all computers.

Comment: Then try loging out of your ubuntu account from all 3 computers and then log in again

Comment: Reading a blog discussion on this, I have the impression that if you click on "Sync between computers" in the Ubuntu Software Centre, you're supposed to get some kind of login prompt.  This does *not* happen.  This comes up: 2012-05-23 12:05:21,219 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file

Comment: Do you know where the configuration file is?  I'd like to look at it to see if somehow it's broken.

Comment: Well no m sorry i cant help u with that.. :(

Comment: Nirmik, you mention logging out and logging in.  Which way?  Where are the "log out" and "log in" options.  Also, which Ubuntu account do you mean?  Software Center?  Ubuntu One?

Comment: okay sorry...its not exactly loging out...my bad..you have to select "stop synching thid computer" from bottom left on all 3 computers and then again select sync between computers...actually when you had selected sync between computers,you must have been asked for your ubuntu account...ubuntu has single account for one software center etc..i can suggest you,remove software center and reinstall..that tme you will be asked to sign in...1st try the stop syncing method and then if that does not work,removing software center.for the timebeing u can install deepin software center in absence of ths 1

Comment: well this is not what you exactly wanted...but it can be helpful if nothing else works--  https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptoncd/

Comment: Okay, in software center I stopped syncing of my computers, then restarted syncing. But the other computers no longer show up on the list -- there's no computers available to sync with, at least according to software center.  Okay, I'll try removing it and reinstalling it if possible.  But this seems like a strange thing to do -- I have an essentially fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 at present, how can this benefit?

Comment: Why i'm asking you to do this is,till now all the "Earlier Computers" that have shown up on in my list were nothing but previous installs of the OS with earlier versions on this same laptop.!! you get what i am saying??

Comment: Not really -- even if the other listed computers are just phantoms of my retired laptops, sync should allow me to do something with them.  There should be some kind of comparison going on of the installations.  There does not seem to be any happening.  I think software-center is broken.

Comment: I can't purge software-center without purging ubuntu-desktop.  This seems like a waste of time -- my install was clean yesterday, from a reformatted hard drive.

Comment: may be...reinstalling might help...or it might just be that e=when a computer is live...you cannot sync...it has to die...like what has happened in my case...try reinstalling...might help...otherwise apton will help(provided you have not cleaned your apt-cache using janitor..

Comment: Did you try deepin software center...from there you can remove ubuntu software center

Comment: What are you referring to by "deepin software center"?

Comment: Its another lightweight software center just like ubuntu software center..its there in software center... http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/deepin-software-center

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3528/discussion-between-nirmik-and-ryan-budney)